# FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView opens in safari but not in webview

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, webview, facebook-ios-sdk

I have using Facebook login in my app. I am following guidelines of Facebook and using native app if it's installed. When native app is installed it works fine. But when it's not I am having a issue.

I specified **FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView** as LoginBehavior. But when app is not installed it opens up Facebook Login page in safari not in webView. I thought this behavior will open it in webView if Facebook app is not installed in user's device.

Do i need to use any other LoginBehavior to use Native app first and then webView not the safari?

Answer (score 0):

Try this behavior:

**FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView**

It will not redirect to Safari

Comment: According to changed guidelines from Facebook this is not advisable. Now we have to use Facebook app if it's installed. But this will open login page in webView even if user has installed Facebook app. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, very true, you are already checking it if user doesn't have facebook app installed and you dont want use Safari, then this is the only way out, which I have used so far in apps as well.

Comment: Isn't there any default LoginBehavior for this ? I thought FbSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView will work it in a way what name suggests. It will try to open a app but if app isn't installed then will use webView implicitly.

Comment: I had the same problem but I solved it with FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView only

Comment: If i do it this way i have to manually manage everything separately for both native app and webView. Have u done the same ?

Comment: Is this written any where that it will try to open in safari and not in webView with the constant i have used. If so can you please give link to that document ? then it would be great.